# Can't Correctly Import Switch and Route from react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, javassist

I have just installed the `react-router-dom`, and now I am trying to write this line.

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
```

`BrowserRouter` and `Link` are imported successfully. However, I am having an issue in importing `Switch` and `Route`. These are not being imported. FYI, I have installed the latest version of `react-router-dom` that is 5.2.0. **I am having this problem in WebStorm. In VS Code, it works fine**.

Comment: when you say "they are not being imported", how do you know that?

Comment: Actually, I when I hover over Switch the WebStorm says, Cannot resolve the symbol 'Switch'. Same is the case with Route. However, when I wrote the complete code and executed it worked. But, since, WeBStorm was not able to find the Code Reference of them, I thought it is not imported.

Comment: so this is resolved then? you should write an answer or delete the question if there wasn't an issue

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a solution @MuhammadMuaaz ?

Answer (score 2):

Install the router package again, as following :

*npm install --save react-router react-router-dom*

It should now be recognized by WebStorm.
The issue was that you didn't install react-router correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Not related to 5.2.0, but considering that v5 documentation is the first thing you find in search engines, other people could probably land here like me aswell. So, newer versions doesn't have Switch component and that creates an confusion if you don't notice the documentation you found is for older version. So, if that is the case, you should use Routes component instead of Switch, and search v6 documentation explicitly over the net.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem. BrowserRouter could import fine but Switch and Route weren't recognised. The issue is because running `npm install react-router-dom` hasn't installed the dependencies for `react-router` where those modules are presumably located.

cesar__'s answer fixes it:

```
npm install --save react-router react-router-dom
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of the version of react-router if you have version of 4 or maybe 5 then it will consider the Switch but if you have v6 then you have to replace the word Switch with 'Routes' every where it is used(import, tags)

To check the version of it you can refer to package.json
It will work definitely!!
Thank you